# Django RestFramework Redirect failing

Tags: python, django, rest

I am trying to build a csv file using POST and redirecting to GET to download that file. I tried returning a FileResponse/HttpResponse in the post function but the file doesnt download.

But when I do a GET, it downloads the file and doesn't allow to take an input.

So my solution is this:

Do a POST to create the file, redirect to GET and that should download the file.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from .apps import ApiConfig
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
# from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
# from io import BytesIO as IO


# # Create your views here.
class PerfPrediction(APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        request.session['_old_post'] = request.POST

        # if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        alt = data['alt']
        mach = data['mach']
        zxn = data['zxn']
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
        model = ApiConfig.model

        inputs = np.array([[alt, mach, zxn]]).astype(np.float64)
        
        out = pd.DataFrame(model.predict(inputs)).to_csv('out.csv')
       
        return redirect(reverse("save_file"), permanent=True)


class Download(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
    #     old_post = request.session.get('_old_post')
        
        response = HttpResponse(open('out.csv', 'rb').read(), content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize('out.csv')

        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'rf.csv'

        return response






        # response = HttpResponse(
        # headers={"Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="filename.csv"',
        #          #"Content-Type": 'text/csv',
        #          },
        # )
        
        # response.status_code = 2081

        # with BytesIO() as b:
        #     with pd.ExcelWriter(b) as writer:


        # out.to_csv(path_or_buf=response, index=False)
        # with open('out.csv', 'rb') as f:
        #     csv_file = f.read()
        # f = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'out.csv'), "rb")
        # response = FileResponse(f, content_type='text/csv', as_attachment=True)
        # response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=out1.csv'
        # response = FileResponse(outfile)
        # response = FileResponse(open('out.csv'), filename='output.csv', as_attachment=True)

        # outdict = pd.DataFrame(model.predict(inputs), columns=cols).to_dict('records')
        
        # return response
```

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PerfPrediction
from .views import Download


urlpatterns = [
    path('perf/', PerfPrediction.as_view(http_method_names=['post']), name='perf_prediction'),
    path('perf/download/', Download.as_view(http_method_names=['get']), name='save_file'),
]
```

The problem I am facing is after redirect, it pases a GET request to the previous URL.

This is what I get if I just go to /perf/download, the file immediately downloads:

```
"GET /v1/api/perf/download HTTP/1.1" 301 0
"GET /v1/api/perf/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 111
```

This is what I get when I go to /perf/ and enter the inputs:

```
"POST /v1/api/perf/ HTTP/1.1" 301 0
"GET /v1/api/perf/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 111
Method Not Allowed: /v1/api/perf/
"GET /v1/api/perf/ HTTP/1.1" 405 5362
```

The output is same for the GET: 200 but the file doesn't download.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried using HttpResponsePermanentRedirect, as I thought the redirect was temporary, since after redirect, it is sending a get to the previous url, but it results in the same issue

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. How are you doing "go to /perf/ and enter the inputs"?